# How to showing date on mysql 5.7 from first date of month until end date of month on MYSQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i want to ask how to showing the date from first date of the month until end of date of the month
for example i want to showing date from 2021-01-01 until 2021-01-30. i want join this data with my other table.

iam using MYSQL V5.7

i want this result ::

```
| 2019-01-01 |
| 2019-01-02 |
| 2019-01-03 |
| 2019-01-04 |
| 2019-01-05 |
| .......... |
| .......... |
| 2019-01-31 |
```

i try using this Query but doesn't work

```
SELECT DATE(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)-1 DAY) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()))
```

Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is how to return all dates for a single month, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive dates as (
      select date('2021-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dte + interval 1 day
      from dates
      where dte < last_day(dte)
     )
select *
from dates;
```

This can easily be extended to other date ranges by changing the `where` condition.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99d42bd8a81f48c69129e30f87aac074) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Does this works with MySQL!? Gee! I'm getting outdated (long time not working directly with DB servers)

Comment: @Barranka . . . Definitely.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: it's work on MYSQL, thanks very much

Comment: how about MYSQL version 5.7?

Comment: Thanks! Learning something new every day!

Answer (score -1):

Old versions of MySQL cannot generate rows that are not stored in a table. I always find myself building a "dates" table to get this done.

You can use this process:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_dates_table(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
BEGIN
  DECLARE d DATE;
  
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dates (
    date DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  );
  SET d = start_date;
  WHILE d <= end_date DO
    INSERT IGNORE INTO dates VALUES (d);
    SET d = d + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
  END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Execute this procedure:

```
CALL fill_dates_table('2019-01-01', '2019-01-31');
```

Then, use the `dates` table as you see fit.

---

If you're using version 8, consider Gordon's answer.

Comment: Well, I guess we now know the limits of your knowledge!

Comment: @Strawberry Is my code incorrect? If so, please help me (us) improving it. AFAIK, StackOverflow is about helping and finding better answers,

Comment: As you've acknowledged in comments elsewhere, you're opening assertion is incorrect.

Comment: @Strawberry ok... MySQL 5 does not support `WITH`... version 8 does. Changed the first line to reflect this

Comment: @Strawberry did you see the OP makes *explicit* reference to MySQL 5? My answer is not incorrect in that context

Comment: Revisionism sure is fun.